# How can I get my Particle system to show hair on all of the faces

Tags: rendering, particles

I want to create a grass lawn for my house, i have created a Particle system for the grass it looks like i have particals showing everywhere in 3d view but i cant figure out why it will only render  in a few squares the plane is one object with only one modifier
[image]

Comment: Can you post a .blend file? (save a copy after deleting the house if you are worried about sharing your model).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwN4eeXsKnGhanpSV3pFcTltVmc

Comment: here is a link to the file